# websitepanel - Is web site panel support sql server 2014 in its services?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have server that website panel installed on it for web hosting, my question is that

Is web site panel support sql server 2014 in its services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a row in `provider` table to add service sql server 2014

```
USE [WebsitePanel]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Providers]
           ([ProviderID]
           ,[GroupID]
           ,[ProviderName]
           ,[DisplayName]
           ,[ProviderType]
           ,[EditorControl])
     VALUES
           (100
           ,23
           ,'MsSQL'
           ,'Microsoft SQL Server 2014'
           ,'WebsitePanel.Providers.Database.MsSqlServer2014,WebsitePanel.Providers.Database.SqlServer'
           ,'MSSQL')
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

web site panel does not support- sql server 2014 in service, but you can add it in website-panel Database

in Providers table you can add row for this work.

Comment: Please help me more

Comment: I edit my answer